# Wildcard SSL certificate and subdomain levels

Tags: wildcard-subdomain, ssl-certificate

our server url schema is setup like this:

```
customer-domain.extension.clients.example.com
```

For example:

```
customer-domain.net.clients.example.com
```

So the clients.example.com never really changes but customer-domain and extension do.

What would be the most reliable and cheap way to set up SSL certificates for this server?

Thanks,
Slav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RFC states that wildcards are only good for the next level down. So in your above examples you would need to get a wild card for each extension:

`*.extension.clients.example.com`

Personally, I would drop the extension part of your scheme and have a wildcard for

`*.clients.example.com`

Now, some browsers support multiple levels for wildcard certs, but this is not universal and against the RFC anyway.